# How url get constructed by angular2-in-memory-web-api for PUT method?

Tags: angular

I'm wondering, how URL, for PUT method, gets constructed by in memory web api, say suppose app/commentList/0 - here 0 is the id of comment in commentList.

Sample Code of service:

```
updateComment(data: any):Observable<any>{
        const url = `${this.dataUrl}/${data.id}`;   
        return this.http.put(url, JSON.stringify(data), this.options)
                        .map(res => console.log(res))   
    }
```

Sample code of DB:

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular2-in-memory-web-api';
export class CommentsData implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
    let commentList = [
      { id:1, username: 'abc', comment: 'adfasdfasdf' },
      { id:2, username: 'rty', comment: 'qwerqewr' },
      { id:3, username: 'Zaw', comment: 'poiqwer' },
      { id:4, username: 'weew', comment: 'asdflkjmasd' }
    ];
    return {commentList};
  }
}
```

In **updateComment()** method, I'm just hitting url with id parameter, but what if, I want to pass any different parameter, like as 'name'?

Answer (score 3):

You can use parameter name which you have in your in-memory web api database. So in your case, something like this can be used:

```
const url = `${this.unitDetailsUrl}/?username=${data.username}`;
```